# Why am I getting a prompt when using fabric?

Tags: python, networking, authentication, ssh, fabric

When I try to use fabric, it gives me a remote shell after I authenticate. Then when I exit, the fabric task runs. Why is this?

Here's the output I received:

```
user@locahost:~$ fab -H remote_host mytask
[remote_host] Executing task 'mytask'
[remote_host] run: python --version
[remote_host] Login password: 
[remote_host] out: user@remote_host:~>exit
[remote_host] out: exit
[remote_host] out: Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
[remote_host] out: Python 2.6.4
[remote_host] out: 

Done.
Disconnecting from remote_host... done.
```

Right after I log in , I receive the following prompt `user@remote_host:~>` which I have to exit manually.

The contents of fabfile.py:

```
from fabric.api import run

def mytask():
    run("python --version")
```

I'm using fabric version 1.2, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.` tells me it's looking for ssh-agent or somesuch.  Take a look at the .login/.profile/.bash_profile of the host you're connecting to for issues.  Also, try initiating an SSH conneection manually and see if that gives any hints.